# EF Core, Primary Key is not auto generated for Entity which inherit from ICollection

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Here is my Entity:

```
public class StackImage: ICollection<StackFile>
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    private IList<StackFile> StackFiles { get; set; } = new List<StackFile>();

    public StackImage()
    {

    }

    [...] // Implementation of ICollection

}

public class StackFile
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public StackFile(){}
}

stackImage.Add(new StackFile(url));
stackImage= await _stackImageRepository.UpdateAsync(stackImage);
await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

In this sample after UpdateAsync, the StackImage Id is not generated (stackImage.Id == default) but the StackFile Id is correctly generated (stackImage[0].Id == default)

Did you already noticed this problem? My guess is, EF Core see StackImage as a list and doesn't try to generate a new Guid. How to fix this issue?

**EDIT**:
From what I can read on the web and by responses I received, It seems not possible to do it. If someone has the solution, please let us know :)

Comment: it IS a list (or at least a collection) and therefore can't be represented in a row in any table. Therefore it doesn't need a PK property either.

Comment: Why not simply follow the EF standards and expose public `ICollection<StackFile>` property rather than implementing the interface?

Comment: It s a long explanation. The shorst version is, I can have ONE image or MULTIPLE images. So I created an abstract class MEDIA which is inherited. It tooks time to think about the model, this solution was the most efficient for what we want. But if EF Core can't deal with it, yes I will use a public Collection. The Migration generation worked well.
I will wait for few suggestions and see what is the best to do.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want to design a database with (at least) two tables. A table with `StackImages` and a table with `StackFiles`.

You want to design a one-to-many relation between `StackImages` and `StackFiles`: every `StackImage` has zero or more `StackFiles`, every `StackFile` belongs to exactly one `StackImage`. In a database this is implemented using a foreign key.

Hence, **it is not true that a StackImage is a StackFile**. However, you can say that a StackImage has some StackFiles.

Following the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) your classes should be similar to:

```
class StackImage
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every StackImage has zero or more StackFiles (one-to-many):
    public virtual ICollection<StackFile> StackFiles {get; set;}
}
class StackFile
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every StackFile belongs to exactly one StackImage, using foreign key:
    public Guid StackImageId {get; set;}
    public virtual StackImage StackImage {get; set;}
}
```

finally the DbContext:

```
class MyDbcontext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StackImage> StackImages {get; set;}
    public DbSet<StackFile> StackFiles {get; set;}
}
```

Note the use of virtual properties to express the relations between the tables. As the foreign key `StackImageId` is supposed to be a real column, it is not virtual

> In entity framework the columns of a table are represented by non-virtual properties,
>   the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables.

Because I followed the conventions, there is no need for attributes, nor fluent API. Entity framework detects the one-to-many collection and creates the proper tables for you. Only if you want different identifiers for your tables or columns you'll need fluent API or attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your really complete answer, I know the convention but I wanted to try something else in our web api context. Form what I can read on the web and but the responses I got here, It seems not possible to do it.